# Magento 2.1 Translate text to given locale

Tags: magento-2.1, module, locale, translate, arabic

I have a situation where I need to save values in couple of languages, Arabic and English at a save form, So I have two fields with the name `Product Name` and `اسم المنتج` i.e Product Name in Arabic, So I need a way I can translate the value in given locale i.e. `ar_SA`

**Note:** The `Product Name` is the primary textbox where as the `اسم المنتج` will be secondary at the Store View for `en_US` and vise versa in the case of Store View for `ar_SA` so I cannot hard code the text, I need it to be dynamically changed on the basis of current locale of the Store

I tried using `Translate\Adapter` class [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Translate/Adapter.php#L24) but no luck

```
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Adapter as TranslateAdapter;

...

$translateAdapter = new TranslateAdapter();
return $translateAdapter->translate('Edit Product', 'ar_SA');
```

but no luck it returns the same `Edit Product` string, I already have Edit Product in my `i18n/ar_SA.csv` file

```
"Edit Product","تحرير المنتج"
"Save","حفظ المنتج"
"Product Name","اسم المنتج"
"Description","وصف"
"Short Description","وصف قصير"
```

Comment: product name is a magento attribute?

Comment: I have it in my .csv files @AdrianZ.

Comment: Did you get the answer @riksof-zeeshan

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to translate the label from the **Magento Edit Product Page**, i would recommand using the attribute store view label translate from **Stores > Atrributes -> Product**. Go to the needed attribute and change the label for every **storeview** you have.